# Can't submit form inside popover with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form inside Bootstrap's popover :

```
 <button type="button" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:15px" 
        data-html="true" 
        data-content='
        <form id="AjaxloginForm">
         <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token(authenticate) }}">
        <div id="Loginresponse" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <label style="margin-top:10px;" for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" style="width:215px;float:right;">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="overflow:hidden;" >
            <label style="margin-top:10px;" for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" style="width:215px;float:right;">
            </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                           <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked /> Remember me
                        </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="overflow:hidden;text-align:center;" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submitButton">Access</button>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Because the form is a dynamic node (displays only when button clicked) I have set a dynamic listener :

```
$("#AjaxloginForm").on('submit',function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(1);
});
```

Sadly nothing works when the form is submitted, in fact I get the page reloaded as regular forms.
How can I achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is created dynamically, you should use event delegation.,

```
$(document).on('submit', "#AjaxloginForm", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(1);
});
```

You can change the `document` with any of the parent element which is presented on the dom at the time of event binding

Comment: I thought event delegation was what I was doing , what a shame .. 
Can I change document with something more precise ?

Comment: @AymaneShuichi see the edits. Accept the answer if it worked for you